# Почему выводит ошибки Glide, когда я подключаю com.simplemobiletools.commons?

Tags: java, android, glide

Когда я подключаю библиотеку com.simplemobiletools.commons, то Glide выводит в логи следующее:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl is implemented incorrectly. If you've manually implemented this class, remove your implementation. The Annotation processor will generate a correct implementation.
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.throwIncorrectGlideModule(Glide.java:341)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getAnnotationGeneratedGlideModules(Glide.java:333)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:176)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.getRetriever(Glide.java:714)
    at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:753)
    at com.ahihi.moreapps.util.GlideApp.with(GlideApp.java:96)
```